# Replace function in pyPEG

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, replace, pypeg

How can i replace some words in pyPEG? For example i have sentence

*John plays football*

I want replace **John** to **Bob** and compose it to:

*Bob plays footbal*.

```
from pypeg2 import *

class Try(str):

    grammar = 'John ', restline

    # I am think that here should be same callback function, but i have no idea how to type it

f = parse("John plays football", Try)

print(compose(f))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
John plays football
```

Comment: Can you please post what you have already tried?

Comment: Give me a second. I will try to edit post

Comment: @gongarek Once you have found an answer which works, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets other people with your problem know which solution works for you.

Comment: @gongarek What's `restline` (in `grammar = 'John ', restline`)?

Comment: restline is rest of line. In this case: 'plays football'

Comment: @gongarek Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

"John" is the first parameter which is being replaced and "Bob" is the replacement string.

Use `.replace(something, with_something_else)`.

```
from pypeg2 import *

def Try(String):

    grammar = 'John'
    String = String.replace(grammar, 'Bob')
    return String

f = Try("John plays football")

print(f)
```

**Output:**

```
"Bob plays football"
```

Comment: Ok. I edited the post. Your answer is good, but how can I assign the sentence in *Try class*

Comment: @gongarek What is the current output of the program?

Comment: @gongarek Edited my answer. Just realised... You don't need a class for this, you need a function! With a function, you can get a return value (the new string).

Comment: In this case i don't need class, as you can see import pypeg2 is not necessary too. Did you use pyPEG before? I am trying to write a parser. Documentation says: *With pyPEG you're declaring a Python class for each object type you want to parse*

Comment: @gongarek I have never used pyPEG2. I answered your question because I thought you didn't know how to `replace()` things in `strings`. If your initial problem has been answered (the replacing part), please click the tick next to this answer as it will let other people with your problem know which solution works for you.

Comment: This is my foult. My question wasn't wrote carefully. Despite this i don't have answer which satisfy me

Comment: @gongarek If you look at what you asked, your initial question has been answered. For the sake of future users with this problem, please click the tick next to this answer to accept it. This will help those people in the future when they need an answer to your initial question